How to remove the overflowed pixels of an image in flutter?
I am a beginner to flutter, and I have trouble in showing an image as shown in the UX, ie tilted and cropped, this is the code that I wrote for Image.asset() widget
Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('lib/assets/wizard2.png', ),
          ),

this is the output for it
My Image
I want it to look like
Image needed
I tried using fittedbox and aspect ratio from suggestions in ChatGPT, but it looked like this
Output after using aspect ratio and fitted box
I dont understand why there is a gap at the bottom, and also I need help to understand how to drag the image down.
thanks for anyone helpingg <3

Try to wrap your Image with Transform.rotate and give angle as your requirement.

That gap at the bottom is because that the slider indicators and the image are positioned vertically adjacent, the indicators are not 'overlayed' on the image, which can be done using a stack widget.
Now, you can try different fit values for the Image widget. If you want to add sliding images you can have a look at carousel_slider package
